# Is there a way to pin files to the right in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I really like how the git lens extension allows you to quickly navigate between modified files in the source control view. I'm wondering if there is a way to have a similar experience with pinned files in VSCode? I'd imagine it would be a relatively easy extension to write, but it seems silly to do if someone has already done it, or if this feature already exists and I just don't know about it.